# How to wait on async response in Express before responding to AJAX request?

Tags: node.js, ajax, express

I am making an AJAX call to my Express server which then needs to make an async request to a database. I have tried using await/async and also making a promise with `.then`.

The problem is, my server responds automatically after hitting the end of `testfunc` instead of waiting for the promise or the return statement.

This results in an empty value being sent back to the client. Is there some way to get Express to wait on the promise or a return before responding to the AJAX request?

Below is an example of what I am trying.

```
exports.testFunc = function(){

    var data = []

    asyncCall().then(function () {
        //Populate data array

        return { 'data' : data } 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler needs to explicitly write to the express response object when you’re asynchronous function has completed

https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res

Currently the handler will be executed and the return is implicitly interpreted as the response completing.  What’s missing is the connection between your asynchorous operation and the completion of the response.  This should be handled through the express response object.

When your asynchronous operation is complete you can call res.send

Comment: `app.get('/testFunc', (req, res) => res.send( funcs.testFunc() ) )` I have something like this, but the response is sent before the return statement occurs. I know this because the client gets a response before the server console logs anything. (If I put a log statement before the return)

Comment: testFunc needs access to the res object.  You can pass it in as a parameter to testFunc.  res.send needs to be called from testFunc when the async operation is finished. In your comment wxample when a request is received, the test func is invoked, it returns immediately (the async operation is started but) and res.send is called immediately (as you describe In your question)

Comment: Wow, that was incredibly simple compared to what I had in my head. I've been beating my head against the wall. Thank You Very Much!